# PHP - ldap_add userPassword crypt and password_hash

Tags: php, ldap, password-hash

I am using PHP 7.1.
and create LDAP management page.

When using ldap_add() function.
there's ['userPassword'] field.

When I use below code, that works OK. (If salt does not exist, it's fine.)

```
$entry['userPassword'] = '{crypt}'.crypt('default_password');
```

Or below code is also works OK.

```
$entry['userPassword'] = '{MD5}'.'base64_encode(pack("H*", md5('default_password')));
```

But I read PHP recommend `password_hash()` function than `crypt()`.

Can I use `password_hash()` function for LDAP? Is it possible?

UPDATE:

OK. then what what is the best solution for LDAP password ?

```
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
$entry['userPassword'] = '{crypt}'.crypt('defaultpassword', '$2y$10$'.$salt.'$');
```

This does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPs Password-Hashing mechanism is intended for use when you want to handle passwords only within PHP. Then it's great to use `password_hash` to create and `password_verify` to verify the password. The used backend here is completely irrelevant.

LDAP on the other hand uses `ldap_bind` to not only verify a password, but to bind a user to an LDAP-Server. That's like logging into the Server. For that there are different Crypto-Algos that can be used like `crypt` or `md5`(which we do not use anymore…).

As this binding-mechanism can be used by different systems to verify a login, the by LDAP supported Crypto-Algos need to be used so that the LDAP-Server can handle the password-verification.

So when you want to use LDAP-Verification via bind on different systems with the password you are storing in LDAP you will not be able to use `password_hash`.

If you want to use the password only with your PHP-Application you *can* use `password_hash` but I would not put it into the `userPassword`-attribute as that is the one the LDAP-Server uses to verify a password given by bind. And you usually can only read that field when you are authenticated as either an Admin or the user in question, which you won't be able to login as due to the password not being able to be handled by the user. So you'd need to bind to the LDAP as admin-user which adds much more security issues to your application than the use of `password_hash` solves.

And I would also question what sense it makes to use LDAP as backend when you don't use the benefits of LDAP like one password for multiple systems. It's usually much easier to store informations in a database than to setup an LDAP just for a single project.

Comment: as you are asking a new question here: would you mimd also creating a new question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I depends on your directory I guess, but commonly passwords in LDAP are stored with a scheme `{MD5}`, `{CRYPT}`, etc.

If you want to use something else, you have to be compliant with the mechanisms that are supported by the directory you use.

For the advice about `password_hash`, the fact is that :

- `password_hash` is only a wrapper of `crypt` with default options set
- `password_hash` is not intended to create a hash for a dedicated authentication mechanism

  It is recommended for developpers who need to store a hash in a database and compare future passwords against this hash without constraint about the hash mechanism used.

The fact that the LDAP protocol support these authentications, you have to comply with the mechanisms supported by the directory.

So as the `password_hash` function does not seem to provide the choice of the hash mechanism used, I would say that you can't use it. Or at least, it won't provide you more "security" to use it than crypt or other supported and readily available mechanisms in your directory.